# Non-EU citizen in Spain with a valid Italian Tourism Schengen Visa and applying for PhD in Spain, What do I do?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, transition-of-visa-status

I need an advice, I have a valid (short stay) Italian Tourism Schengen Visa, type C. I have earlier applied for a PhD in Spain in my country. Then I got an invite to participate in an academic conference in Italy, therefore I had to travel to Italy, immediately after the conference, the University in Spain sends me an email for an interview (which was last week) for the PhD programme and I have to stay longer than the days of my schengen visa (which expires on the 17th of October) to process my PhD in Spain, because there is a phase (from October 29 - November 6) of Self-Registration. I do not want to risk missing my admission for the Phd programme since I am in Spain. If I go back to my country today or tomorrow, there is no way I will be able to come back before the 29th of October.

What do I do since I came to Spain with an Italian Tourism Schengen Visa, type C and it will soon expire?

Comment: Can you clarify the dates you’re talking about? It’s not clear from your question a) when the PhD interview is; b) when you plan to leave Spain; and c) when your current visa expires.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that information, I went to the immigration office today and I was told to go the local police office. I will go there on Monday because tomorrow is a public holiday in Spain.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look good.

I would try asking at the oficina de extranjería (or, if none exists where you are, the local police station) whether they can extend your stay with a temporary residence permit, but normally Schengen short-stay visas are supposed to be extended only in case of emergency, so probably they cannot.

They may have another solution, but I wouldn't give that a high probability, either.

You can also try going to another country, closer than your home country, and applying for a Spanish visa there; the country you should go to would depend on your nationality and whether you already hold any other visas.  This is also unlikely to succeed, unfortunately, because of the rules that require people to apply in their place of residence.  It is possible for exceptions to be made when a reason for travel arises after you have left home, and this certainly seems to qualify, but in practice it appears to be difficult to get consulates to acknowledge this possibility.  It is probably even more difficult to get the third-party processors that are increasingly used to acknowledge it.

Your best bet is probably to talk to the university, explain your visa situation, and see whether they can either allow you to register while you are outside of Spain or at a different time.

Comment: +1 for talk to the university and explain situation. As far as the university knows, the OP is in their home country and the university should be able to accommodate travel requirements.

Answer (score 2):

The situation you describe should make it possible to request a Spanish visa while in Italy. Usually people should apply from their place of residence, but the rules allow exceptions when plans change on short notice.

I don't know if the Spanish embassy will agree that yours is a hardship case, and if they will process the application fast enough.